# Comparison of two list in python

Tags: python

I want to compare two lists, if both have the same word with its match number. The match number is important here. I did it in this way;

```
    List1= ['john', 'doe','sima']
    List2=[]
    test = "John is with Doe but alina is alone today."
    List2 = test.lower().split()
    n=0
    counter=0
    while n < len(List1):
        for i in range(len(List2)):
            if List1[n] == List2[i]:
                print("Matched : "+str(counter) + List1[n])
                n=n+1
                counter=counter+1
            else:
                print("No match :"+ List1[n])
#             break
#         break
```

The program is working fine, if both lists have the matched words. But for unmatched word `sima`, the loop is running infinite times. If break the `for` loop in `else` and then break the `while` loop just after it as comment is telling in the code, the program run for first match only. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

```
 while n < len(List1):
        for i in range(len(List2)):
#         print("Matching :"+ List1[n]+ " : "+ List2[i])
            if List1[n] == List2[i]:
                print("Matched : "+str(counter) + List1[n])

                counter=counter+1
            else:
                print("No match :"+ List1[n])
            n=n+1
```

Giving `IndexError: list index out of range` error

Comment: use set and & .

Comment: move the n = n+1 line to the end of the loop outside the "if" condition. If the "if" condition fails, then n never increases and the loop goes on

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn See the edit1 in question

Comment: @YOU I need `counter` for each match. How can I get counter using `set` and `&` ?

Comment: A list works from 0 to n-1. If you type list[n] it will give you an error saying list index out of range

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn Thanks `move the n = n+1 line to the end of the loop outside the "if" condition` worked for me.

Comment: But your solution is not elegant. Look into my answer for optimizing the code

Answer (score 2):

From your code, this will work. Although not the most elegant way of writing it, here is your code

```
List1= ['john', 'doe','sima']
List2=[]
test = "John is with Doe but alina is alone today."
List2 = test.lower().split()
n=0
counter=0
while n < len(List1):
    for i in range(len(List2)-1):
        if List1[n] == List2[i]:
            print("Matched : "+str(counter) + List1[n])
            counter=counter+1
        else:
            print("No match :"+ List1[n])
    n=n+1
```

And this is your result

```
Matched : 0john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :john
No match :doe
No match :doe
No match :doe
Matched : 1doe
No match :doe
No match :doe
No match :doe
No match :doe
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
No match :sima
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List1= ['john', 'doe','sima', 'alina' ]
List2=[]
test = "John is with Doe but alina is alone today."
List2 = test.lower().split()
counter = 0
for word in List1:
    try:
        index_number = List2.index(word)
        counter += 1
        print("Matched : " + str(counter) + " " +  word + " at " + str(index_number))
    except:
        print("No Match Found")
```

Although solution to your problem is already answered by others still its not elegant. As in the question you mentioned that the match number is important, so I am giving you my way of solution for the problem. Please look.

Comment: @ Harry, thanks for writing it in an elegant way. from his code what I see is someone who just started so I did not want to use advanced code to make it hard for him, upvoted.

Comment: Yeah that's why I upvoted your answer. But I still thought to write it for his future references :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to a small problem. You are increasing `n` in `if` body which means increasing the variable if the condition is met. In your case, when it reaches to `sima`, the condition is not met and so n will not be increased. So you need to increment `n` after `for` loop.